# Падает програма после освобождения памяти

Tags: c++, malloc, free

Пишу свой класс string, и возникла проблема, после самописной конкакенации, при вызове деструктора падает программа. В чем может быть проблема? Кучу времени потратил на дебаг, и не нашел причины.
Подозрения на перегруженный `оператор +`.
среда: Visual Studio 2019

**КОД:**

```
class  String
{
private:
  char* mem;
unsigned  int sizeofthis;
public:
  using iterator =StringIterator;
  String():mem(nullptr),sizeofthis(0){}
  String(const char*str):mem(nullptr),sizeofthis(0)
  {
    if (str != nullptr) {
      unsigned int i = 0;
      while (str[i] != '\0') {

        sizeofthis++;
        i++;
      }
      i = 0;
      mem = (char*)malloc(sizeofthis + 1);
      if (mem != nullptr) {
        while (str[i] != '\0') {

          *(mem + i) = str[i];
          i++;
        }
        *(mem + sizeofthis) = '\0';
      }
    }
  }
  String(char*str):mem(nullptr),sizeofthis(0)
  {
    if (str != nullptr) {

      unsigned int i = 0;
      while (str[i] != '\0') {

        sizeofthis++;
        i++;
      }
      i = 0;
      mem = (char*)malloc(sizeofthis + 1);
      if (mem != nullptr) {
        while (str[i] != '\0') {

          *(mem + i) = str[i];
          i++;
        }
        *(mem + sizeofthis) = '\0';
      }
    }
  }
  String(const String &s):mem(),sizeofthis()
  {
    this->mem = s.mem;
    this->sizeofthis=s.sizeofthis;
  }
  unsigned int Size() const  
  { 
    return sizeofthis;
  }
  void Out() {
    for(size_t i=0;i<sizeofthis;i++)
    {
      cout << *(mem + i);
    }
  }
  char operator[](unsigned int i) const 
  {
    if (i < sizeofthis) {
      return *(mem + i);
    }

  }
  ~String() { 
    free(mem); 
  }

  void operator+(String next) {
    mem = (char*)realloc(mem, next.Size() + this->Size() + 1);
    if (mem != nullptr) {
      int k = 0;
      for (int i = sizeofthis; i < next.sizeofthis + sizeofthis; i++) {
        *(mem + i) = *(next.mem + k);
        k++;
      }
      *(mem + next.sizeofthis + sizeofthis) = '\0';
      this->sizeofthis += next.sizeofthis;
    }
  }

};
```

***main.cpp***

```
int main()
{ 
  String sta("DIO");
  String ahah("JOTARO");
  cout << sta.Size() << endl;
  cout << ahah.Size() << endl;
  sta + ahah;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: В конструкторе копирования написана чушь. Разумеется, все будет падать. Зачем вы вообще писали такой конструктор копирования, если он ничем не отличается от неявного? Также не понятно, почему используется инопланетянский синтаксис `*(mem + i)`, причем впепемешку с человеческим `str[i]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Издеваетесь, да? :)

```
String(const String &s):mem(),sizeofthis()
{
    this->mem = s.mem;
    this->sizeofthis=s.sizeofthis;
}
```

Итак, вы копируете указатель, который в деструкторе освобождаете. Значит, как только у вас появляется копия (а она появляется - раз тут

```
void operator+(String next) {
```

идет передача по значению, т.е. с копированием) - так сразу происходит дважды освобождение одной и той же памяти. Что очень хреново...

Может, есть и еще ошибки, но эта просто бросается в глаза...

Comment: не добавите в ответ как нужно?...